# Deciphering Basement Bathroom Rough-In

Tags: plumbing, bathroom, rough-in

The original owner of our house had the layout changed from the standard design and we need some help with deciphering what's what so we can try to figure out what the new idea was that he was envisioning.

Can someone help with identifying what each of these are for?
Thanks in advance![image: ![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qe81Z.jpg)

Comment: The marks on the floor, were they put there by to original owner, or by you? The DS by #3 which will be the toilet, and the TX or TA by #6 really does not give any insight unless you may know or can find out.